# List intent available android wear

Tags: android, android-intent, wear-os

I try to start activity from a watchface or a app android.

I able to start the view to choose watchface when user tap on watchface :

```
@Override
public void onTapCommand(
       @TapType int tapType, int x, int y, long eventTime) {

   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER));
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

I want start other activities like Google Agenda, Google fit, or other ...
It's possible to list all intents available on the device ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will return all of the launcher activities on a device:

```
public static List<ResolveInfo> gatherApps(Context context) {
    if(allApps == null) {

        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> infoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        Collections.sort(infoList, new Comparator<ResolveInfo>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ResolveInfo lhs, ResolveInfo rhs) {
                return lhs.loadLabel(packageManager).toString().compareTo(rhs.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
            }
        });

        allApps = infoList;
    }
    return allApps;
}
```